# API responds with unicoderror... but if I first try the request through the browser, it goes through

Tags: python, api, rest

I'm using stubhub's api to try to perform some LCS queries.  If i try to send a get request through, I get an UnicodeEncodeError, but if i send that same get request through the browser, it works, and then immediately after sending it through the browser, also works in the script, correctly returning the JSON response.

Any time I change the parameters, it goes back to failing, until I first try it in the browser.

What would cause this?